# Break in if-Statement

Tags: c, if-statement, do-while, break

I wrote the following code:

```
int main(void){
    double (*func[]) (double) = {func1, func2, func3};
    int option = 0;
    double sum;
    double result;
    do{
        scanf("%d", &option);
        if(option == 3){
            break;
        }
        scanf("%lf", &sum);
        printf("%.2lf\n", result = (*func[option])(sum));
    } while (option<10);
    return 0;
```

But when I input 3 it expect another value and exit.
How can I break after entering 3?
Also is there a better expression for the do-while-loop instead of option<10.
It is supposed to run until option = 3.

Edit: scanf is supposed to be used (not my choice)
Someone asked for an example (input, output):

Choose an option: **3**
(nothing happens, until I input another value)
**4**
(here it exits)

Comment: Please [edit] and show an example of input and expected output.

Comment: `scanf` is hard to get right, I would strongly recommend reading complete lines to a temporary buffer with `fgets` and then parsing from there (e.g., with `sscanf`, `strtol`, etc.).

Comment: It only makes sense to boundary check `option`. And since you for some reason is using signed numbers, you have to do `if(option >=0 && option <3)` before calling the function pointer.

Comment: Have you checked what the actual value of `option` is? Use a debugger or a simple printout.

Comment: @TedLyngmo that was a typing error. I edited my question.

Comment: @klutt yes, i checked it. When I printout option it prints 3 and when i debug the code it also breaks after option is set 3.

Comment: "_When I printout option it prints 3 and when i debug the code it also breaks after option is set 3_" - Isn't that what you want? You asked "_How can i break after entering 3?_" and you now say that that's what it's doing.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work that way when running the actual program.

Comment: @atelten Then I suspect that you are not running a program compiled with the same code you use when debugging. You are probably running an old version of the program.

Comment: What @TedLyngmo said. Introduce a printout with a random sequence in beginning of main. If you don't see it, then it's what Ted said.

Answer (score 0):

You *must* *always* check the value returned by scanf.  I would write this with a while loop rather than a do/while.  (Actually, I would completely refactor this and avoid scanf completely, but that's a different issue).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
        int option = 0;
        double sum;
        while( 1 == scanf("%d", &option) && option != 3 ){
                if( 1 != scanf("%lf", &sum) ){
                        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
                        return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
                printf("option = %d, sum = %lf\n", option, sum);
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

That code doesn't give an error message if an invalid option is entered, but since this is apparently intended to be used interactively, printing an error message and terminating is probably not the desired behavior.  Perhaps you want to do something like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void
eat_line(void)
{
        int c;
        while( (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' ) {
                ;
        }
        if( c == EOF ){
                fprintf(stderr, "EOF\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}

int
main(void)
{
        int opt;
        double sum;
        while( 1 ){
                while( printf("enter an option: ") && 1 != scanf("%d", &opt) ){
                        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
                        eat_line();
                }
                if( opt == 3 ){
                        break;
                }
                while( printf("enter a value: ") && 1 != scanf("%lf", &sum) ){
                        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
                        eat_line();
                }
                printf("option = %d, sum = %lf\n", opt, sum);
        }
        return opt == 3 ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

but IMHO trying to make a program using scanf that is user friendly is pointless.

Comment: Well, in order to be user friendly you typically need system specific functionality. If you are running interactively you typically want to discard the rest of a line after an input format error because stdin is line buffered; how you actually parse input is largely irrelevant for that, and scanf is handy for parsing.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica That's a good point.  The code I have here will spew repeated error messages.  ick.